# Handling Pre-Fetched Dynamic Client Routes in Gatsby / @ReachRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, reach-router

I have this scenario.

- A user types in `/company/<company-id>` in the address bar.
- Since the app is totally separate from the backend, it needs to prefetch the companies.
- Normal user flow is `/login` -> `/company/`. I handle this case pretty well and just navigate to `/company/<whatever id is first in the prefetch>` with no problems.
- But what if you load *WITH* the id? I have solution but I think I have a feeling that I'm misunderstanding something in routing.

You may assume that my prefetching works and the code snippet below will only trigger if `companyState.success` is true. Like i said, it is working.
I handled this manually, by

```
// pretty sure i can handle this with regex better to capture other cases
// but that's beside the point for the scope of this question
const urlId = +location.pathname.replace("/company/", "")
const checkCompany = !!companyState.data.find(d => d.id === urlId)
if(checkCompany){
  company.set(urlId)
}
else{
  navigate("/404")
}
```

I have hooks in place where in if `company.set(<company:id>)` does update, it will pre-fetch everything else needed for the view. And, `company` is a custom context hook so that it's present everywhere in my application.

Is there a better way in handling this? It seems hack-y to manually check the path name. 
You can assume that my `gatsby_node.js` has the right definitions to allow the client side routing.

Here's my routing definitions: (this is what i put in the pages folder)

```
const DashboardPage = () => (
  <ProtectedRoute>
    <Router>
      <Company path="/company/*" />
    </Router>
  </ProtectedRoute>
)
```

Finally in the components folder,

```
const Company = ({location}) => (
    <Router>
      <Main path="/:companyId">
        <Summary path="/" />
        .... other dashboard routes
      </Main>
    </Router>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assume that client-side code can always be changed by a malicious actor. Ultimately, you have to make sure on the backend that a user can only request ressources he is supposed to see.

Your solution for the client-side seems fine to me. I don't see another way than checking the URL path manually and then redirecting.

By logging in, your user needs to be assigned to a cryptographically safe cookie or token (such as JSON web tokens) so you can always be sure of their identity. Everytime a company id is routed to, your frontend needs to send the user identity to your backend. Only there you can be safe from code manipulations. Your backend needs to check if the user can look at this page.

- If the user can: your backend sends the page data
- If the user can't: your backend sends "not authorized" message and your frontend redirects

This way even if someone manipulates your client-side code and cancels the redirect, the hacker will stare at a useless blank page.

**In summary:**

Your approach on the client-side is fine. Make sure your backend checks the identity of your user before sending the company data.

Comment: Yes of course the backend is protected, goes without question. Thanks for the answer! I actually solved it in a better way than what I did.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of me manually handling the routing, I solely used ReachRouter's navigate to simulate `history.push()` to avoid re-rendering of the whole page. (similarly just a state change with the benefit of keeping track of history ). Backend is fully protected with auth tokens so no need to worry about that.

My strategy below will handle these cases:

- User types in or app navigates to `/company` ( app will pre fetch > get first company by default > navigate to `/company/{id}`
- User types in or app navigates to `/company/{id}` ( app will pre-fetch > navigate to `/company/{id}` > component triggered by that route will check validity of id else navigate to 404 )

The strategy I created was,

- Create a component that will load up a loading screen by default and prefetch the said companies.
- Call the said component in the `pages` folder as the default, in my case, `/company` should be `pages > company.js` or `pages > company > index.js`
- If the prefetch is successful, navigate to `/company/{id}` which is the child of the said component, which is a purely client route.
- make sure `gatsby-node.js` have the necessary `createPages` definition to allow client routing for everything `/company/*`
- manually check if the current location is `/company` to deny redirection to capture the second case when user types in `/company/{id}`

Better if I show the code, ignore my custom built in hooks.

`useRequest` just gives an axios class, with the `true` parameter telling it's an authenticated required request. 
`useApi` just gives a handy (async-await) function that includes `dispatch` for the redux states and calling the api itself. I'm using thunk, so `success` and `error` are standard.

```
const CompanyDefault = ({location}) => {

  const [loading, toggle] = useState(true)

  const request = useRequest(true)
  const companyApi = useApi(request, getCompanies)
  const companyState = useSelector(({company}) => company)
  const redirectToCompany = async () => await navigate(clientRoutes.COMPANY(companyState.data[0].id))

  const fetchCompanies = async () => {
    await companyApi()
    toggle(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(companyState.data.length === 0){
      fetchCompanies()
    } 
  }, [])

  if(loading){
    return <Loading />
  }
  else if(companyState.error || companyState.data.length === 0){
    return <Error callApi={companyApi} />
  }
  else if(companyState.success && (location.pathname === "/company" || location.pathname === "/company/")){
    redirectToCompany()
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <Company path="company/:companyId/*" />
    </Router>
  )
}

export default CompanyDefault
```

Thus, the company module will be just

```
const Company = ({companyId}) => (
    // you now have companyId! 
    // do magic here, and check if that company id is valid.
    <Router>
      <Main path="/">
        <Summary path="/" />
        .... other dashboard routes
      </Main>
    </Router>
)
```

Hopefully this is cleaner. If there's a better way do let me know! :D